# PYTHON: Percentage of sorting level of a numpy 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

Monotonicity percentage is how sorted an array is in ascending or descending order.
I need a python (preferably numpy) way of achieving this consider the following example

```
   array([[2,3,4,6,5] # 60% sorted
         [1,2,3,4,5] # 100% sorted
         [0,2,4,8,10]# 100% sorted
         [0,2,4,8,10]]# 100% sorted
         /  | |  \  \
        /   | |   \  \
    100% 100% 80% 80% 100%

Monotonicity percentage is average(80,100,100,100,100,100,80,80,100)
```

I want to run this in an AI heuristic, speed is very important, thanks for any help

EDITED
This is what I have for now it simply return a bool and it is 1D

```
def mncity(arr):
    dx = np.diff(arr)
    return np.all(dx <= 0) or np.all(dx >= 0)
```

I am new to PYTHON generally

Comment: Sorry but this is not a coding service. What have you tried so far? Where sre you struggling?

Comment: Thanks for that @ImanolLuengo

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this using `zip()` and `list comprehension`:

```
def get_pourcent(a, order='ascending'):
    if order == 'ascending':
        # Check if every element is inferior than his next in the list
        b = [1 if j < v else 0 for j, v in zip(a, a[1:])]
        # Get how much zeros in b
        zeros = len(b) - sum(b)
        percent = (1 - (float(zeros)/len(a)))*100

    elif order == 'descending':
        b = [1 if j > v else 0 for j, v in zip(a, a[1:])]
        zeros = sum(b)
        percent = (float(zeros)/len(a))*100

    else:
        return None

    return '"%s": %.2f%% sorted' % (order, percent)


# Test
tests = [('ascending', [2,3,4,6,5]), ('ascending', [1,2,3,4,5]),
 ('ascending', [0,2,4,8,10]), ('descending', [2,3,4,6,5]), ('descending', [0,2,4,8,10])]

for k, v in tests:
    print v, get_pourcent(v, order=k)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 6, 5] "ascending": 80.00% sorted
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] "ascending": 100.00% sorted
[0, 2, 4, 8, 10] "ascending": 100.00% sorted
[2, 3, 4, 6, 5] "descending": 20.00% sorted
[0, 2, 4, 8, 10] "descending": 0.00% sorted
```

**Edit:**

```
tests = [[ 2, 4, 0, 8], [ 4, 24, 0, 16], [ 16, 2, 16, 32], [ 16, 2, 16, 128]]

for k in tests:
    print get_pourcent(k)
```

Will output:

```
"ascending": 75.00% sorted
"ascending": 75.00% sorted
"ascending": 75.00% sorted
"ascending": 75.00% sorted
```

Comment: I like the solution, was thinking the same thing, but this code could be much more clear

Comment: @DanielSanchez Why not? . Give me your suggestions and i'll edit it :-) I'm open to any suggestions. Don't hesitate :-)

Comment: you use an if when the code is the same but changhing 1 single operator, also using itertools.izip and itertools.islice instead of zip would be nice, so you would not create intermediate lists just for checking, i would also just return the percent result :)

Comment: True, but the code will be more complicated to read I don't think that the OP can understand it. But, i'll add a new edit with a new code. Thanks :-)

Comment: @DanielSanchez, look closely, under the `if` the code isn't the same. The operation changes not only the operators.

Comment: thats it, it shouldnt

Comment: @DanielSanchez Can you post an answer ? Do it if you want

Comment: What about using numpy? And the function is also not working as expected it gives 100% for this `array([[  2,   4,   0,   8],
       [  4,  24,   0,  16],
       [ 16,   2,  16,  32],
       [ 16,   2,  16, 128]])`

Comment: what about that behaviour?

Comment: oh! I am sorry for that, I omitted the second higher array braces

Comment: Regarding clarity, it's a one liner in numpy... and probably much faster too.

Comment: @P.Camilleri it's one line but you have to import numpy module. Sometimes we don't need to use a bazooka to open a door, a simple key can do it smoothly.

Comment: @ChihebNexus it doesn't apply if the door lock is crap and you would have to turn your key manually 100000 times to open the door. A bazooka might be better then. In addition, numpy comes preinstalled with most modern python distributions, so not importing it can't be used as an excuse.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take the diff along an axis (0 or 1), then see the proportion of positive values along this axis:

```
(np.diff(a, axis=1) > 0).mean(axis=1)
```

The same can be done for the columns with `axis=0` in diff and mean.

I'm not sure why you want 80 % and not 75 % for the first row, but if you want that you can do:

```
(np.diff(a, axis=1) > 0).sum(axis=1) / a.shape[1]
```

and for columns:

```
(np.diff(a, axis=0) > 0).sum(axis=0) / a.shape[0]
```

Comment: @Camilleri can you please complete this answer to be a callable?

Comment: well you can just define a function of a which return the line I've written, it's straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function that I built and work as expected

```
def merge(mat):
  monotone = 0
  matrix = numpy.copy(mat)
  for i in range(4):
    m_vertical = 4 if numpy.size(numpy.where(numpy.diff(matrix[:, i]) < 0)[0]) == 0 else numpy.where(numpy.diff(matrix[:, i]) < 0)[0][0]+1
    m_horizontal = 4 if numpy.size(numpy.where(numpy.diff(matrix[i]) < 0)[0]) == 0 else numpy.where(numpy.diff(matrix[i]) < 0)[0][0]+1
    monotone += (m_vertical + m_horizontal)*3.125
  return monotone
```